# How to set an image to ImageView of different layout using MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

**I am trying to set ImageView of different layout. I tried using a LayoutInflator to initialize the ImageView also ensured that ImageView has got an image (img.getDrawable() returns true) but still image is not showing up.**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView img;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_success_booking, null);
    img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_2);
    
     img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_success_circle_green_72dp);
    

        new SwipeDismissDialog.Builder(this)
                .setLayoutResId(R.layout.dialog_success_booking)
                .build()
                .show();
        if(img.getDrawable()==null)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image doesn't exits",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image exits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_success_circle_green_56dp);
            
    }
}
```

**Dialog_Success_Booking.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_add_user_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="dialog_success_title"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here, I just quickly Googled the library and from what I can understand, here is what you can do. You can set the dialog via View instead of from Layout Resource.

```java
SwipeDismissDialog dialog = new SwipeDismissDialog.Builder(this)
                .setLayoutResId(R.layout.dialog_success_booking)
                .build()
                .show();
    

img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_2);
    btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_success_circle_green_72dp);
    btn.setText("Download");
```

We need to store the dialog reference, show it, then use it and `findViewById` to make the changes.

Secondly, replace the compile with implementation. This is just a general advice

```
implementation'com.github.andreilisun:swipedismissdialog:0.1'
```

Comment: Even that didn't work and am already using implementation. I have edited my question.

Comment: @ErenYeager Tell me why don't you simply assign the drawable in XML itself?

Comment: Because i'll loading image from url instead.

Comment: @ErenYeager I feel we need to show the dialog first and then edit it, since the dialog is not visible at the moment, all the changes we are setting is not visible. I am updating the answer with the code. Please try that and revert back.

Comment: This is not working. Image is still not showing up.

Comment: @ErenYeager I ran your code and I figured it out. I am updating the answer. Please try again. Although I tried in Kotlin, the same should work fine in Java.

Comment: Woow great its working fine. You were right I did make a bit mistake.